# Setting the alpha of a layer border?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am setting a border to my `layer` by adding the following line of code:

`[self.avatar.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];`

How can I change the alpha on just the border and not the `avatar` object as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `UIColor`'s [`+colorWithWhite:alpha:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW9)

```
[self.avatar.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.5f].CGColor];
```

If you need a color other than white, use [`+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW11) as already mentioned by user3386109.

Answer (score 14):

**For Swift-3 Version**

```
 let opacity:CGFloat = 0.6
 let borderColor = UIColor.white
 self.view.layer.borderColor = borderColor.withAlphaComponent(opacity).cgColor
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5]`.  A value of 1.0 for red, green, and blue makes the color white, and you can change the alpha to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

With [`-colorWithAlphaComponent:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/colorWithAlphaComponent:) you can easily do it for any `borderColor`

```
CGFloat opacity = 0.5f;
self.avatar.layer.borderColor = [borderColor colorWithAlphaComponent:opacity].CGColor;
```